# Multiple flexslider remove current slide

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to remove the current slide from a flexslider on a page with multiple sliders who currently share the same class. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

What it currently does is if I click on the close link to remove the current slide on the 2nd flexslider, it removes the current slide from the 1st flexslider.

I need it to correctly remove the current slide on the respective sliders. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<!-- flexslider 1 -->
<section class='choices'>
  <ul class='slides'>
    <li class='flex-active-slide'>
       <a class='close'></a>
       content here
    </li>
    <li>
       <a class='close'></a>
       content here
    </li>        
    <li>
       <a class='close'></a>
       content here
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<!-- flexslider 2 -->
<section class='choices'>
  <ul class='slides'>
    <li class='flex-active-slide'>
       <a class='close'></a>
       content here
    </li>
    <li>
       <a class='close'></a>
       content here
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**script**

```
(window).load(function() {

    $('.choices').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
    });

    var slider = $('.choices').data('flexslider');

    $('.slides .close').click(function(){
         slider.removeSlide(slider.currentSlide);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to found a workaround, the currentSlide only return the slide index number. So it requires more specific selector.

```
$('.choices .close').click(function(){
    var sliderid = $(this).closest(".choices");
    var slider = sliderid.data('flexslider');
    slider.removeSlide(slider.currentSlide);
});
```

Comment: How could I do this to remove a specific slide (in my case slide 3) I know I can usse $('#flexslider').flexslider(3); but I am wanting to remove a slide when browser width is > 1024px and it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: I think you can do $('#flexslider').removeSlide(2) to remove the 3rd slide because its using the slide index which starts from 0.